# odoo statusbar widget visible

Tags: xml, odoo, statusbar

How to only show selected items from selection to statusbar.

I inherited a view which Selection  has only 'draft' and 'sent'.
Then I added 'cancel'.

```
state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('sent', 'Sent'),
    ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
    ]
```

I wanted to only show draft and sent. How to make the cancel invisible?
or how can i make selected item statusbar invisible?

Answer (score 3):

Find the statusbar in the view that you want and replace it with an xpath:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="hide_cancel">
    <field name="name">Hides cancel button</field>
    <field name="model">your.model</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="the_view_that_contains_the_statusbar" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='state']" position="replace">
           <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,sent"/>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,sent"/>
```

Comment: Actually, there's already selection 'state' which has only 'draft' and 'sent'. I inherit its view and add a new state 'cancel'.....and now the cancel statusbar will show.. i don't know how to make the cancel in statusbar invisible.

Comment: Then please describe it fully in your question. Please update your questions.